# Angularjs. Inheritance scope in nested directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angular, angular-directive

At the moment, trying to write code in a Angular2 style, i.e. without the use of controllers. Faced with the problem of data transfer from the external and internal directive. How to do it correctly?
The main question is how the inside of the directive to access the external scope and use the data in the template of internal directives? Example
[on codepen](http://codepen.io/powerman23rus/pen/NNwMPJ)

```
<test-directive>
  <nested/>
</test-directive>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified you codepen, see my modified [version](http://codepen.io/xie-qianyue/pen/XdzOqP).

```
class Nested {
  restrict='E';  
  template='<p>Nested {{inner.outer}} {{inner.last}}</p>';
  controller=function(){
    this.last='Pupkin';
  };
  controllerAs='inner';
  bindToController={
    outer: '=' // a communicating point of outer and inner directives
  };
}
```

The point is that, in `bindToController`, you can add your endpoint variable, as `outer` here. And in the outer template, give it a value like: `<nested outer="outer.first"/>`.

@Günter Zöchbauer's answer is for the Angular 2.

Also, If you want to see a whole example of using component style with Angualr 1, you can see my [express-angular-es6-starter](https://github.com/xie-qianyue/express-angular-es6-starter/blob/master/client/app/components/todoPage/todoPage.html), A todo mvc with ES6 and component style Angular 1 codes.

Comment: Thank you! I knew something like this, but I think that it is quite time-consuming, or am I mistaken all the same?

Comment: And you can explain when to use bindsToController? Because I'm writing it in each directive, is it right? I've noticed that you use it as an object, and I thought that this is of the variable is boolean...

Comment: And is it possible to link the past and future with the help of ng-transclude? for example, access to the values of "max" and "min" slider in paddle?  Like in this --> [template](http://codepen.io/powerman23rus/pen/RaxaEP) <--link

Comment: @powerman23rus here is a good [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html) for `bindToController`, it can be a boolean or an object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass values explicitely

```
<test-directive>
  <nested [someInput]="somePropertyOnParent"></nested>
</test-directive>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nested',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`)}
class Nested {
  @Input() someInput;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.someInput);
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution Angulyar 2, but I have to do the same thing, only using Angular1! But thanks anyway)